# Cannot bind background to button in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm trying to bind the Background property of a standard button to a property I have in my viewmodel like this:

```
<Button Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,515,0,0" x:Name="BtnReset" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ResetBtnImage}" />
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

The property is as follows:

```c#
    private ImageSource _resetBtnImage;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the reset button image.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The reset button image.
    /// </value>
    public ImageSource ResetBtnImage
    {
        get { return _resetBtnImage; }
        set
        {
            _resetBtnImage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ResetBtnImage");
        }
    }
```

And then I set it in code:

```
ResetBtnImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ResetBtnInActiveImage, UriKind.Relative));
```

However the button doesn't show up at all when I try and run the app on the phone or the emulator. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: do you get any binding errors in the output window? try changing the XAML to be incorrect, then verify that the error is showing in the output window, sometimes, you can simply not bind something to a datacontext and spend hours fixing something that is not bound :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's how I would do it:

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Test" Background="{Binding MyImage}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private ImageBrush _myImage;
public ImageBrush MyImage
{
  get { return _myImage; }
  set
  {
    if (_myImage.Equals(value))
      return;
    _myImage = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("MyImage");
  }
}

 _myImage = new ImageBrush();
 _myImage.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Background.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. Your image may not being packaged and deployed with the app correctly. Check that your image path is correct and that the Build Action is set to Content.
2. The data-binding may not be working. Check for binding error messages in the debug output window in Visual Studio which would point to potential data-binding problems.

Comment: All my images are set to 'Content' and 'Copy Always' and I don't get any binding errors :(.

Comment: Updated the property to be of type 'ImageSource'. But that didn't help either. It shouldn't have been a string to start with. Just corrected it. But yea, I'm still stuck.